# multiple rolls probability

Tags: probability

I have a $20$ sided die.

I roll it $5$ times. Each time I get a number between $1-5$.

What are the odds for or against this outcome?

(It would be great to have a formula. Intuitively, I don't think the answer could be merely $1/4$, but I don't know how to calculate it.)

Comment: The 20 sides of the die are numbered 1-20?  If yes and if the outcome mentioned is to get FIVE times  in a row a number between 1-5, the answer is NOT $1/4$.  It will be $(1/4)^5$, that is $1/1024$.

Comment: With all these fine answers, it is your move to Accept one of them. Perhaps soon you will know how to find the distribution of the random variable $X$ that counts the number of times out of 5 rolls you get a number 5 or smaller.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

1. If you roll 1 time, what are the odds of getting it beteen 1-5? Say this is $p$.
2. If oyu do this 2 times in a row, you need $p$ to get your result the first time, and another $p$ to get your result the second time. So to get ittwice in a row, you will get a probability of $p \times p = p^2$.
3. What happens if you need to do this $5$ times in a row?

Answer (score 1):

The rolls are independent. The chance of rolling 1-5, 5 numbers out of 20, are the same each time. Independent rolls means you multiply the probability for each event. Here you roll five times with a probability of 5/20 each time to get the five lowest numbers. $P = (\frac{5}{20})^5$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the set of symbols on our die is $\{a_1,a_2,\cdots a_k\}$. Some symbols might be on more than one side. We might assume that the die doesn't remember the previous rolls to conclude that the probability in $n$ rolls we only get $a_j$ with $p\le j\le q$ is
$$
\left({\sum_{j=p}^q\text{number of sides with the symbol }a_j\over \text{number of sides}}\right)^n
$$
In the current case this gives you $\left({5\over20}\right)^5$.

Comment: Why the downvote? Did I miss something? The op asked for a general formula...